# Which is faster? Native HTML Select options or SELECT options populated using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML page with a few Select input with more than 50 options each. I wonder whether it is faster to load the HTML options by populating them via JQuery , or I just put all the `<options>` in the HTML form. The JQuery method will allow me easier to maintain in the future, I just need to update the JSON data.

The client might add more options in the future but my main concern is the efficiency. Neither database nor internet is available for the page, the main consideration is Javascript or pure HTML.

UPDATED: JQuery is always loaded on the page which sits in the same box(locally)

Comment: Obviously if they already exist it's faster to render. But whether they exist in html or not it's your decision how to render them based on maintainability. Note that is is very easy to copy, sort and manipulate whatever already exists. What are you needing to do?

Comment: Faster to what? Render? Open dropdown? If native means you won't include the jQuery library, the page will load faster for sure. If you include jQuery anyways, the difference will probably be negligible.

Comment: if you have a fixed set of options, you might want to prefer HTML code. If you put the options in Jquery, the select in HTML will nto be populated till the jquery loads and populates it.

Comment: Faster in terms of time to fully load the page. I know it might be less than a second and I personally thinks the native HTML will be faster, it just something that cross my mind especially with modern browsers which has powerful Javascript engine.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript and jQuery can't do anything with the  elements until the elements have been loaded into the DOM. The text contained within those elements are also inserted into the DOM as nodes on load while javascript and jQuery sit idly waiting. When jQuery finally gets to work on those text nodes, it's a relatively slow process. So, HTML will always be significantly faster than loading them with javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The pure HTML-option is almost assuredly faster for the end-user, since the jQuery option requires first waiting for the jQuery library and then the DOM to load before the (document).ready() function even fires. That said, there are many ways to optimize your JS to make the page load quickly. One way is to use a CDN version of jQuery (Google provides one as well as other sources). The advantage there is that anyone who's browsed to a site that also used the same CDN version of jQuery will likely have the library already in their browser cache. You could also look into simply using plain old javascript to load up the select box so you don't have to wait for the library to load.